# Conditional breakpoint in Dart

Tags: dart, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I am trying to set a conditional breakpoint when the answer "black" is selected on my Dart project and I cannot figure out how to get it to do this.

I tried "debug when 'answer' = 'black' in the conditional breakpoint options but am not having any luck.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.